# Android INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, gradle

I just updated my Android Nexus 6P from Android 7 to 8 and now one of my applications can't be installed. When trying to install app from android studio I get this error

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.
```

After looking into this problem I found different sources that said to add code below to `build.gradle` file.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

This did not fix the problem, what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Run this command to check ABI of your device: adb shell getprop "ro.product.cpu.abi"

Comment: The command returned 'arm64-v8a'. Which I included in the abi.

Comment: Thanks to @W0rmH0le and `adb shell getprop | grep cpu.abi` to view abilist as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `apache.commons-io` version 2.4 library. Not sure why but the library was causing some crash that was not letting the application install. Once I updated to version 2.5 everything installed properly.

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem! Good catch.